# std::map - decrement iterator gives strange result?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, iterator, undefined-behavior

Can't seem to work this out. Simple example as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {

    std::map<uint32_t, char> m;
    
    m[1] = 'b';
    m[3] = 'd';
    m[5] = 'f';
    
    std::map<uint32_t, char>::iterator i = m.lower_bound('d');
    
    std::cout << "First: " << i->first << std::endl;
    
    // Decrement the iterator
    i--;
    
    // Expect to get 1, but get 5?
    std::cout << "Second: " << i->first << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
First: 3
Second: 5
```

Why do I get 5 here? I thought decrementing the iterator would result in it pointing at key 1

Comment: Do not that `lower_bound` takes a `Key`, not a `Value`, so looking for `'d'` as a `uint32_t` is going to fail and return the `end` iterator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This call

```
std::map<uint32_t, char>::iterator i = m.lower_bound('d');
```

returns the iterator `m.end()`. So dereferencing the iterator

```
std::cout << "First: " << i->first << std::endl;
```

results in undefined behavior.

The member function `lower_bound` expects an argument that specifies a key not value.

Consider the following demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    std::map<uint32_t, char> m;

    m[1] = 'b';
    m[3] = 'd';
    m[5] = 'f';

    std::map<uint32_t, char>::iterator i = m.lower_bound( 'd' );

    std::cout << "i == m.end() is " << std::boolalpha << ( i == m.end() ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
i == m.end() is true
```

Instead you could write for example

```
std::map<uint32_t, char>::iterator i = m.lower_bound( 5 );
```

After decrementing the iterator after this call

```
std::map<uint32_t, char>::iterator i = m.lower_bound('d');
```

it points to the last element of the map.

Comment: I actually transposed the question wrong when simplifying it, but this simplified version does give the output I posted. I was searching for a key in my original code, but you gave me the hint I needed to check for end() there and I fixed my bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`lower_bound` takes as input the key, not the value. This would do as you expect:

```
std::map<uint32_t, char>::iterator i = m.lower_bound(3);
```

With the `lower_bound` you are using, you end up finding `end()` and iterating back one.